# How does OS select an interrupt handler?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have read a few pages about interrupt handling and I am getting more and more confused as to how OS actually selects an interrupt handler to execute.

I read the following:

> The CPU asks this question ('Where is the interrupt service routine?') to the hardware by issuing an interrupt acknowledge, and the hardware answers the question by placing an interrupt vector number on the data bus. The CPU uses the interrupt vector number to find out where the interrupt service routine is.

This is one of the things, the other included

1. Each device having a IRQ harcoded i,.e, each device actually has an interrupt number determined by the line that connects the device to the CPU. That is then used to find the handler in the IDT
2. hardware that causes an interrupt places the interrupt number in a special registry, which the CPU then reads and uses as interupt number to lookup the handler in the IDT

Does any of this make sense and which one is actually correct?

Comment: The answer is already given in the text you quoted. "The CPU asks the hardware, and the hardware answers the question by..." and "each device actually has an interrupt number determined by the line", and "hardware that causes an interrput places the...in a special registry, which the CPU then reads". In all of those places, it discusses the CPU and hardware - there's no OS involvement. Therefore, they're all correct.

Comment: The question should be, how does the processor specify the device requesting an interrupt? If you pursue that then it will be easy to understand what the OS does. Note that there are a variety of ways that processors do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually varies quite substantially based on the actual hardware you're using.

The overview is this:

1. A hardware event occurs in a particular device.
2. The device asserts a signal on its interrupt line.
3. The interrupt line is often connected to an interrupt controller, a dedicated piece of hardware that decides whether to signal the processor.
4. The interrupt controller decides to signal the processor.
5. The processor switches to interrupt mode and begins executing the interrupt handler installed by the OS at a predefined location.
6. The interrupt handler asks the interrupt controller which interrupt line was actually signaled, which tells it which device sent the interrupt.
7. The interrupt handler dispatches the interrupt message to the device driver.

You are asking about steps 6 and 7. Step 6 depends on the interrupt controller. Some interrupt controllers are actually inside the processor die physically, in which case the "ask" is simply a matter of reading the right memory addresses. Some are on a bus, in which case the processor has to take ownership of the bus, signal the interrupt controller, and have it reply with the interrupt line number.

Step 7 is defined by the OS entirely. The OS might have a table mapping interrupt lines to interrupt function handlers, and that table might be predefined (as is usually the case on embedded systems where the hardware layout is fixed), or it might have been determined during startup as the system discovered what devices were attached to it.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure why step 5 would happen in the manner you describe. If the interrupt handler is at a pre-defined location, there can be only one. However, I was under the impression that there were many interrupt handlers and the O/S would figure out which one to call somehow. So in fact I was asking about step 5 which I believe would execute slightly differently